# Software to read .uif files?

Tags: file-format

I downloaded a file with .uif extension. What this extension means? What software is need it to open these kind of files?

Comment: sometimes it is better to search from Google. search by "uif file extension" and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stands for Universal Image Format.  It's a proprietary compressed format for storing CD and DVD images.  There are several programs that handle them, including MagicISO and PowerISO.

Answer (score 2):

You could also convert them to `iso` using [UIF to ISO converter](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm)